# Laravel : How can I insert nested list in MySQL database?

Tags: laravel, insert, nested-lists

I have to send such as below list to an API created by Laravel ,I have two table ,first is order contain id and user_id and ,and the seconde is order_items contain details:

```
[
 {
    'id' : 1,
    details :{
    {
       'item' : 'PC',
       'qty' :  3
    },
    {
       'item' : 'TV',
       'qty' :  2
    }
   }
 }
]
```

I send them as post like this (using flutter) :

```
send_order(items ) async {
    var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/user/order';
    var response = await http.post(url ,body : items);
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return (data);
  }
```

also I have this controller in Laravel :

```
public function order(Request $request){


}
```

I want to insert them together ,but I don't know how to do that

Comment: Depending on your database you can create `JSON` columns and insert the JSON. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-json

Comment: I have two table  ,first is order contain id and user_id and ,and the seconde is order_items contain details

Answer (score 0):

You can insert nested data into a [JSON column](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-json). You can then use [JSON where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses) for convenience.

I wouldn't recommend this though, because the correct database design here would be to create a [one-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) between the `order` table and the `order_items` table. One `Order` will have many `OrderItems`.

In `OrderItem.php`:

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
}
```

In `Order.php`:

```
public function orderItems()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
}
```

Using `$order->orderItems` would then return a collection of `OrderItem` belonging to the `$order`.

Comment: Ideally `order` and `item` would be a `many-to-many` relationship, where "an Order can have many Items, and an Item can belong to many Orders". What you're suggesting with a one-to-many would result in many duplicated Items.

Comment: already I created the relationships as you mentioned ,and I used it for get data ,but can I use it for inserting ?

Comment: @TimLewis that's a good call, unless OrderItem records have data unique to the Order, such as quantity of this specific Item that was ordered. Hard to know without more info.

Comment: @Sermedmayi You can do something like `$order->orderItems()->save($items)`.

Comment: That would simply be an additional column on the pivot table between `order` and `items` :) But yeah, more information is definitely helpful. Just from my experience with eCommerce systems, limiting a single item (or product) to only be part of a single order is probably not the best approach to data normalization :)